# When ReactJS meets Facebook Audience Network Mobile Web Native Ads

Tags: facebook, reactjs, facebook-audience-network

Anybody knows how to deal with the `fb:ad` tag when generating the virtual DOM in React.js?

When I compiled the jsx/babel file, there's an error:

> Namespace tags are not supported. ReactJSX is not XML.

below is the sample code of [the layout of native ads of mobile web of facebook audience network](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/mobileweb/javascript/native-web)

```
<body>
    <fb:ad placementid="[PLACEMENT_ID]" format="native" nativeadid="ad_root"></fb:ad>
    <div id="ad_root">
        <a class="fbAdLink">
            <div class="fbAdMedia thirdPartyMediaClass"></div>
            <div class="fbAdTitle thirdPartyTitleClass"></div>
            <div class="fbAdBody thirdPartyBodyClass"></div>
            <div class="fbAdCallToAction thirdPartyCallToActionClass"></div>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook was aware of the in-house nature of its mWeb Audience network source code and modified its way to display its web native ad component. They now use standard divs with IDs referred in the script. In that case, you then need to use the following code instead to render the Facebook native ad elements (grab the class or assign an ID) :

```
<body>    <div class="fb-ad" data-placementid="[YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID]" data-format="native" data-nativeadid="ad_root" data-testmode="false"></div>

<div id="ad_root">
      <a class="fbAdLink">
        <div class="fbAdMedia thirdPartyMediaClass"></div>
        <div class="fbAdTitle thirdPartyTitleClass"></div>
        <div class="fbAdBody thirdPartyBodyClass"></div>
        <div class="fbAdCallToAction thirdPartyCallToActionClass"></div>
      </a> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I also found an easy but not recommend way - put the line of fb:ad tag as: {<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: fb_ad}} />} in the render method.